# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation error handling

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, duplicates

I know what the error means, and why it's occurring, meaning this is not a duplicate of the many topics covering State 23000. I'm using PDO to insert a duplicate record into a table that has a compound PK. I did this on purpose, in order to automatically cancel the insertion of any duplicated records in to this specific table.

The error, `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation`, is killing the script. Is there a way to set the warn level for this particular error, to literally tell it to shut up and carry on?

I don't understand the purpose of having compound PKs if we can't allow them to work for us?

I'm not very experienced with DB administration so you'll have to forgive me if I come across a bit 'it should work if I hit it with a hammer'.

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `cart` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `itemid` int(10) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `unique_records` (`userid`,`itemid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note the compound PK called 'unique records'.

so I have this table:

```
| id | userid | itemid |
|  1 |    175 |     12 |
```

And I execute this query:

```
    $insertItem = $db->query("
                              INSERT INTO cart (userid, itemid) 
                              VALUES (:userid, :itemid), 
                              array("userid"=>"175", "itemid"=>"12")
                            ");
```

Executing this query prompts this error: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation`.

I fully understand why I'm getting this error - I just don't understand why it's killing my submission? I thought it should just keep working ignoring the fact that a few records weren't inserted because they were duplicates?

Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `insert` to keep working, you can try using `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO cart(userid, itemid) 
    VALUES (:userid, :itemid);
```

`INSERT IGNORE` can be a bit strong because it ignores all errors.  If you just want to ignore duplicate key errors, use `on duplicate key` and set a value to itself:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO cart(userid, itemid) 
    VALUES (:userid, :itemid)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY userid = values(userid);
```

The `set` part does nothing -- the value doesn't change -- but the effect is to ignore the error.

Comment: I like this a lot and haven't used IGNORE before, thank you! +1

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be quite vague - either you want to ignore your integrity constraint violations, or you want them to be a signal saying "no more inserts".

In addition to the answer with `insert ignore` solution - when you execute your query and get `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation` error, that means PDO throws exception. If you don't `catch` it, your script is killed. If you don't want it to be killed, wrap your DB code into try-catch construct, i.e.:

```
try {
    // code here
    $insertItem = $db->query("
                              INSERT INTO cart (userid, itemid) 
                              VALUES (:userid, :itemid)", 
                              array("userid"=>"175", "itemid"=>"12")
                            );
    // more code here
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // handle exception - 
    // find out if it is caused by integrity contraints violations
    // and if it is - merely go further
    // otherwise do something else, like re-throwing your exception
}
```

HTH

Comment: +1 I've just learnt that if you catch errors they don't kill your script. I honestly didn't know this :) thank you!

Comment: the question is how to detect if it was caused by integrity constraint violations? I know it is but I'm not sure what the if statement would be to see it's exactly that violation

Comment: @iBobb the easiest thing coming to my mind - make a test script and `var_dump` the exception variable `$e` - it should contain some code or SQL state denoting you have "integrity constraint violation" - see the above "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation", so presumably it will contain "23000" as error code

Comment: I searched around and did this: catch (PDOException $e) {
`if ($e->getCode() != 23000) {
      $status = "status 0" . $e;
    } else {
     $status = "status -1";
    }`